# How would you remove all objects from an array?

Tags: javascript

So, how would you remove all objects from an array.. My current code is:

```
            var array = [""];
            function add() {
                var input = document.getElementById("enterInput").value;
                array.push(input);

                var arrayOut = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = array;
            }

            function clearit() {
                var length = array.length;
                array.splice(0, length, length);
                array.push("");
            }
```

Thanks, Noah..
(and yes, I have checked the console and no errors are returned.)

Comment: Don't pass a third argument to `splice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
function clearit() {
    array = []; //or array = [""];
}
```

Comment: Clean and simple solution

Answer (score 1):

maybe just redo the array

```
array = [""]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also use:

```
    array.length = 0;
```